# Assign selected tag on items dynamically using multiselect plugin in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I've met next problem using this set of plugins(multiselect and jQuery).

I have static list in select tag. I've set it with smarty(php) and wrapped it with multiselect plugin. Then I recieve json data with ajax request and finaly i want to make items in static list selected. So... i'm using next thing.

```
$("select#search_operation").change(function(){
            $.getJSON("ajax_oper_workers",{order_id: $("#search_order_id :selected").val(), operation_id: $("select#search_operation").val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(data){
            //  alert();
                var options ="";
                for (var key in data) {
                    $("#worker_"+data[key].id).attr('selected', 'selected');
                };
                $("#workers_select").multiselect("refresh");
            });
        });
        $("#workers_select").multiselect({sortable: false, dividerLocation: 0.51, width: 1000});
```

Clicking on the submit button sends post and there i can see that correct items were send. But before clicking on it i want to see that items on the left side of the multiselect view. I supposed that my code should work, but it doesn't. It doesn't put correct items on the right side of the view.

For clearly understanding here is the picture of how it looks like.
[image: multiselect]

Comment: I dont quite get how it should work. You search for something, then get an JSON with the results, and you want all the results as selected?

Comment: Yeap, you get it. And after that they must dissaper from the right column and appear on the left side.

Comment: After what? Im confused to what needs to be in the left, and what needs to be in the right? :)

Comment: Oh, understand. I'll try to explain. Right side of the list is loaded when page is renered. Afeter that i can choose/type some data in input fields. When the last field is changed, multiselect must go on. I've checked it with alert and it gave me right values in '"#worker_"+data[key].id'. So i'm sure that it works correctly. But multiselect doesn't want to refresh itself when changes happend.

Comment: It seems you dont "render" the multiselect once the NEW data is inputted, so you need to run the multiselect function in the getJSON succes function. Could you post some sample JSON data, then ill try to make it in JSFIDDLE :-)

Comment: I rerender it with "refresh" method(which doesn't refresh it at all). You can see it in the code above. I can't get why do you need json data? Json data is correct. It was tested in validator.

Comment: Try doing `$("#worker_"+data[key].id).attr('selected', true);` i seem to remember its a better soloution. Just wondering where you found the refresh fucntion. Because on the github page, it dosent have it in the plugin (https://github.com/michael/multiselect/blob/master/js/ui.multiselect.js)

Comment: Yeah :( Already have found that i was watching documentation to other multicelect plugin. And this doesn't support ajax. So my problem can be solved wuth only a patch i suppose. Or with a hack :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need AJAX use this one:

https://github.com/michael/multiselect/tree/next

This is the exact same plugin, just with AJAX functionality :-)

Hope it helps!